# Can you set public / private read access for azure blobs in the same container?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

The Azure documentation says that storage blob containers can be made with public or private read access [(see here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#about-anonymous-public-read-access). This says that public access can be set to 'Container' or 'Blob', and explains the differences in the table.

However, it isn't clear if, having set the container with Blob level public access:

```
container.CreateIfNotExists(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.PublicAccessType.Blob);
```

This implies that the public read access is set on a blob by blob basis, and if so, how to set it up.

However, I am not sure this is true? I have seen various other posts about copying blobs around between different public/private containers, which somewhat backs up my thinking. The client creation doesnt appear to have a public/private setting:

```
BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(filename);
```

... and using the above coding, then all blobs created have public access.

My problem is that I need to allow users to change the state of uploaded images/videos to public or private. I am wondering if there is a less cludgy way than moving the blobs around between private and public containers..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public access is a container level setting.
There are two options for public access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#set-the-public-access-level-for-a-container.

- Public read access for blobs only (Blob): Anonymous requests can get blobs by their full URL (caller must know the container and blob name)
- Public read access for container and its blobs (Container): Anonymous requests can get blob list for the container (caller must only know container name)

So I would say that yes, you either have to move them between containers or handle the authorization on your side.

Answer (score 1):

Your right in your assumptions, the access level is defined on the container.

To workaround your issue, I would suggest granting access to all blob's using Shared Access Signatures. That way your application logic can control access, but all downloads still happen directly from blob storage.

The correct way to do this would be proxy all request via your application logic before redirecting the user to an blob url including the shared access signature. That way you can revoke a link later.

An example flow would then look like:

1. User access https://example.com/images/myimage.png
2. Application logic determines if "images/myimage.png" should allow anonymous access or if the user should be redirect to login
3. If access is allowed, the application finds the correct blob in blob storage, and generates an SAS signature
4. The user is then redirect to "https://example.blob.core.windows.net/images/myimage.png?sastokenstuffhere

Comment: Thanks @Nisd ... I am already using SAS Keys for the internal application, this just comes down to if, for example, the user wants to send a link to the image in an external email message.

Comment: Have the link be to your application, then have that attach the SAS and redirect to the blob storage?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine until the user want to send the image to someone external eg. In a link in an email which won't time expire. I guess I could maybe generate a sas key that doesn't expire.. and provide that as the link maybe..  Worth a look..

Comment: Sadly the above (my comment) wont work since it will create a non expiring key for a blob which is a risk..

Comment: I have updated my answer so you hopefully can understand what I suggested.